# Babel 6.0.20 Modules feature not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, babeljs

I am trying to export a es6 module in `header.js`:

```
export default {
    setHeaderHighlight: function (index) {
        // do somethings
    }
};
```

And import it in `index.js`:

```
import header from "./header.js"

$(function () {
    header.setHeaderHighlight(0);
});
```

Then transformation comes out in `index.bundle.js`:

```
var _header = __webpack_require__(129);

var _header2 = _interopRequireDefault(_header);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; // crash here
}
```

So here is the problem, ie8 will rise a `Expected identifier` Exception at `{ default: obj }`, but everythings is ok >=ie9.

Is there something i can do with this?

Comment: I found a temporary solution: `webpack -p` will do the same thing of that two babel es3 plugins.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default, Babel 6.x requires you to enable an explicit set of transformations. The standard `es2015` preset converts ES6 to ES5, however IE8 is not ES5-compatible. In this case, if you look at the [plugins list](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/), you will see

- [transform-es3-member-expression-literals](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es3-member-expression-literals)
- [transform-es3-property-literals](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es3-property-literals)

These will convert your properties to be compatible with IE8. Generally in Babel 6.x you'd do this by passing those names as part of your `plugins` array, alongside the `presets` array and install the transforms via

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals
```

Comment: I install the plugins, add them in `.babelrc` and restart the build. But it still not work. Is there something I miss?

Comment: @Bruce Looking into it, my steps are what _should_ work, but they aren't. I've filed a bug: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2817

Comment: The solution above worked for me, but note if you have a default module import like `import * from 'jquery'`, it will still expand as `_jquery2.default` which uses the 'default' reserved keyword, breaking IE.

Comment: Yeah, here's a snippet from compiiled babel code, even using the two es3 pugins mentioned above: `exports.default = {` when exporting an object literal as the default export of a module

Comment: @loganfsmyth could you add a link to the issue on phabricator? Couldn't find it when I looked now

Comment: Phabricator link is here: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2817 The issue numbers are the same as the old Github ones.

Comment: Who is up voting this? This dosnt solve the issue for me at all! Crashing at the exact same spot.

Comment: If you have a specific case that isn't working, please file a bug. This is the correct answer, and if it doesn't work we need bug reports.

Answer (score 6):

I use webpack + [es3ify-loader](https://github.com/sorrycc/es3ify-loader) as workaround.

```
loaders: {
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['es3ify', `babel?${JSON.stringify(babelQuery)}`],
  },
}
```

Comment: I tried that approach but I'm getting "Parse Error: Line 1: Missing from after import" but does not make any sense :/

Comment: Fixed it, order matters :)

Comment: Note: in Webpack2 you must name the `es3ify` loader as `es3ify-loader` - and `babel` as `babel-loader`, took me half an hour to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

I also have the problem, and I wrote [a webpack plugin](https://github.com/BryceHQ/es3ify-webpack-plugin) to resolve it.  I didn't really know if there is a nicer way to handle it, but it works.

The module in node_modules also works well.