# Getting Babel 6 to work with IE8 (via. Gulp/Webpack)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, webpack, babeljs

I've got Babel 6 working nicely with Gulp and Webpack. I now need to polyfill it to get IE8 support.

I've installed the babel-polyfill, but can't get it working and the docs and Google haven't helped so far.

**My Gulp task (inc. Webpack config):**

```
gulp.task('webpack', function(callback) {
  var webpackConfig = {
    context: __dirname + '../../../js',
    entry: {
      homepage: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './public/homepage/homepage.js'
      ]
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '../../../dist/public/scripts/',
      filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          test: /\.js$/, // Only run .js files through Babel
          include: /js/, // Only include the /js dir
          query: {
            //plugins: ['transform-runtime'], // Disabled pending fix to https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2954
            presets: ['es2015'],//, 'stage-0'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  webpack(webpackConfig, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      throw new gutil.PluginError('webpack', err);
    }

    gutil.log('[webpack]', stats.toString({
      // output options
    }));

    callback();
  });
});
```

From the docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/):

> **Usage in Node / Browserify / Webpack**
>
> To include the polyfill you need to require it at the top of the entry point to > your application.
>
> require("babel-polyfill");
>
> **Usage in Browser**
>
> Available from the dist/polyfill.js file within a babel-polyfill npm release. This needs to be included before all your compiled Babel code. You can either prepend it to your compiled code or include it in a  before it.
>
> NOTE: Do not require this via browserify etc, use babel-polyfill.

I've tried simply adding the polyfill.js file to the top of the page, but IE8 still isn't happy with the compiled code's use of the `default` keyword.

I've also tried adding the polyfill to the webpack process, as per http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/ and other suggestions from Google

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and looks like you now need separate babel plugins for the `default` and other keywords, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33513000/5169258

Comment: Thanks - that thread explains what's going on. Wish they'd fix the shoddy documentation on this!