# How to polyfill Array.prototype.find using webpack ProvidePlugin?

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, webpack, polyfills

I'm using webpack and have followed examples to polyfill fetch and Promise for older browsers based on the whatwg-fetch and and es6-promise packages respectively.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    'Promise': 'exports?global.Promise!es6-promise'
}),
```

This all makes sense however now I need to polyfill [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) but can no find of how to achieve this using webpack's ProvidePlugin feature. The thing that makes find different is that it is essentially a *method* on the Array prototype and I haven't found any examples of how to specify such things using ProvidePlugin. Has anybody used webpack to polyfill [ES6 array functions](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) like these? Any pointers on how this can be achieved? Am I going about this the wrong/outdated way or is there a better way to achieve what I need?

So far I've tried experimenting around with the syntax using [this polyfill package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.find) from [paulmillr](https://github.com/paulmillr) but haven't had success using it with ProvidePlugin.

#### UPDATES

Doing more research on this lead me to babel polyfill. And these resources:

- [Why does Object.assign() require a polyfill when babel-loader is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148218/why-does-object-assign-require-a-polyfill-when-babel-loader-is-being-used)
- [Babel polyfill? What is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122193/babel-polyfill-what-is-that)
- [Getting Babel 6 to work with IE8 (via. Gulp/Webpack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695218/getting-babel-6-to-work-with-ie8-via-gulp-webpack)

I've found also [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) that the window.fetch polyfill is missing from babel-polyfill which explains why it's perhaps often a special case handled by ProvidePlugin. I'm also piecing together that ProvidePlugin is more of a convenience tool than a general tool for applying polyfills. Directly importing babel-polyfill and removing Promise and other ES6 pollyfills except for fetch is showing to be somewhat promising in my experiments so far.

Comment: ProvidePlugin can only replace things it can statically detect, so there is no way it can replace `find` because it's just a method on an object. Why use ProvidePlugin instead of a global polyfill?

Comment: I'm not sure... It's the solution I was pointed to when asking how to deal with missing _fetch_ and then subsequently _Promise_ so I just assumed I would do something similar for each polyfill I need.

Answer (score 3):

What I've settled on for now is the following solution.

In the root of the application import/require [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/#installation) for general ES6 polyfills such as *Array.prototype.find*, *Object.assign*, and *Promise*. Since *fetch* is a special case, because it is viewed as not suitable for all environments, a separate polyfill is included for [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch).

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import "whatwg-fetch";
```

In the webpack configuration remove any ES6 features provided through the ProvidePlugin but leave any other conveniences there (ex. JQuery orz).

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    // 'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    // 'Promise': 'exports?global.Promise!es6-promise',
}),
```

This should give me more rounded ES6 support with manually opting in for each feature I make use of. My hope is that Babel 5/6 will be able to Tree-Shake any unused feature that may otherwise cause bloat by including all of babel-polyfill, perhaps somebody else can speak to that.