# Can babel transpiled code run in browser without polyfills

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm very much interested to use ES6 features in my current project. I checked out and found couple of options: TypeScript and Babel. I'm planning to try Babel. My worry is, the code I write in babel after traspiling can it safely run in IE9? or do I need polyfills still?

Comment: I'm inclined to say Nothing can safely run in IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, code generated by Babel will run in IE9 ([there are caveats](https://babeljs.algolia.com/docs/advanced/caveats/#internet-explorer), you need to use [plugins in Babel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512715/babel-6-0-20-modules-feature-not-work-in-ie8/33513000#33513000)).

However, Babel only transpiles ES**2015/6** language features (new syntax changes, keywords, etc). If you want to use ES6 built-ins such as `Promise`, `WeakSet/Map` and so on, you will need a polyfill for non-compliant browsers.

Comment: And some new syntax features depend on new library features, so if you don't polyfill, you can't use those either, like `for...of` with `Symbol.iterator`.

Comment: Can Babel import `@babel/polyfill` by default?  Do I have to import it in my app?