# "transform-es3-member-expression-literals" usage in webpack 1.x

Tags: internet-explorer-8, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am working on application that needs to be run on IE 8 enterprise version.I am getting following errors in the console:
Expected identifier : ;
indexOf is not available for the object.

For solving this I read this question on stackoverflow:
[Babel 6.0.20 Modules feature not work in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512715/babel-6-0-20-modules-feature-not-work-in-ie8/33513000#33513000)
It suggests

transform-es3-member-expression-literals
transform-es3-property-literals

to be added.
But using this in webpack is not mentioned any where,not on babel official site.
Can anyone suggest the way how can I use it as a plugin to my project.

Note:I have already tried doing

```
var es3MemberExpressionLiterals = require('babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals');
var es3PropertyLiterals = require('babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals');
plugins = [// Plugins for Webpack
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: false}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html', // Move the index.html file...
    minify: { // Minifying it while it is parsed using the following, self–explanatory options
      removeComments: false,
      collapseWhitespace: false,
      removeRedundantAttributes: false,
      useShortDoctype: false,
      removeEmptyAttributes: false,
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: false,
      keepClosingSlash: true,
      minifyJS: false,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyURLs: false
    }
  })
 new es3MemberExpressionLiterals(),
 new es3PropertyLiterals()

];
```

Comment: Did you find a fix? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [demo repository on github](https://github.com/dotcs/webpack-babel-es3-plugins-example) to show the full configuration by an example.

To get the two plugins running create a `.babelrc` file, with the following content

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es3-member-expression-literals",
    "transform-es3-property-literals"
  ]
}
```

In the standard configuration `babel-loader` in your `webpack.config.js` babel takes a look into the `.babelrc` to configure plugins.

```
// webpack.config.js (partial code only)
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  ]
}
```

If everything is set up correctly webpack should transform the following code

```
// src/main.js
var foo = { catch: function() {} };
console.log(foo.catch)
```

into

```
// bundle.js
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    var foo = { "catch": function () {} };
    console.log(foo["catch"]);

/***/ }
```

See also the examples for the plugins: [babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals) and [babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals).

Comment: Awarded the bounty because it actually works as I asked, but I'm afraid I didn't explain myself correctly.  My problem was something else.  Anyway I sorted it out in a different way.  Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Thanks for awarding the bounty. Sad to hear that this was not your actual problem in the end but I'm also glad that you found a solution for the real problem in the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

The question you link to is about Babel plugins, and you are trying to pass them as Webpack plugins. You'd need to set up Babel as a loader for your application and pass the plugins to that. Merge the following into your Webpack configuration.

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    loader: 'babel',
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals',
      'babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals',
    ],
  }],
},
```

Comment: That didn't work for me.  Is there any other way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Define "didn't work"? What specifically did you get? Might be worth asking a new question.