# React IE 8 compatibility issue with axios

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, axios, babeljs

I am developing a react application that will run inside a legacy Java application container that is set to use IE compatibility mode i.e. IE 8.

I get the error in IE8 or lower:
`SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier`
on the following line, on the `default` keyword:

```
module.exports.default = axios;
```

I have added 
    `"transform-es3-member-expression-literals" & "transform-es3-property-literals"` in my `.babelrc` and installed the packages, but it does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel 6.0.20 Modules feature not work in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512715/babel-6-0-20-modules-feature-not-work-in-ie8)